# Reading messy JSON using php

Tags: php, json

Hello I've got this really messy JSON that I would like to read data from but I can't think of a way to do it.

It looks like this

https://pastebin.com/55pWWgnK

```
  {
    "capacity_test": {
      "date": "2017-03-01",
      "status": "done",
      "PROPERTIES": {
        "fail": {
          "capacity_test": {
                    .
                    .
                    .
          },
          "def": [
            {
              "drop_test": {
                "Properties": {
                  "date": "2017-03-05",
                  "status": "done"
                }
              },
              "waves_test": {
                "date": "2018-03-06",
                "status": "done"
              }
            },
            {
              "drop_test": {
                "Properties": null
              },
              "waves_test": {
                "date": "2018-03-06",
                "status": "done"
              }
            },
            {
              "drop_test": {
                "Properties": null
              },
              "waves_test": {
                "date": "2018-03-06",
                "status": "done"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "final_test": {
          "Properties": null
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

PROPERTIES is not the same as Properties and this json array is recursive, it can have infinite amount of "capacity_test" inside one another.

My issue is that I would like to check if there is a "status" key with no value in there somewhere.
This JSON is quite messy, I tried to come up with a recursive php function such as:

```
$this->myFunction($json, 'capacity_test');
public function myFunction($json, $step, $status = 0)
{
    if ( is_object($json->$step) ) {
        if ( isset($json->$step->status) ) {
            if ( !empty($json->$step->status) ) {
                $status = 1;
            }
        } else {
            foreach ( $json->$step as $item ) {
                if ( is_object($item) ) {
                    $status = $this->myFunction($item, $step, $status);
                    if ( $status === 0 ) {
                        exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $status;
}
```

This doesnt seem to work for me

Comment: that's not even valid json, how do you parse it?

Comment: @steros What isn't valid about it?

Comment: @steros remove the three dots...

Comment: I have no choice, I have to use this at work, this is generated by another app using js libs.

Comment: Yes it's my bad, I added the dots because it's huge.

Comment: Paste it eg at pastebin

Comment: @Artas ah okay, I didn't get that

Comment: could be more handy for processing if you decode json into associative array instead of object
`json_decode($jsonString, true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code should help you. Implement your own logic, when status is empty.

```
<?php

$jsonString = '{
        "capacity_test": {
          "date": "2017-03-01",
          "status": "done",
          "PROPERTIES": {
            "fail": {
              "capacity_test": {
                "date": "2017-03-02",
                "status": "done",
                "PROPERTIES": {
                  "boolean": false
                }
              },
              "def": [
                {
                  "drop_test": {
                    "Properties": {
                      "date": "2017-03-05",
                      "status": "done"
                    }
                  },
                  "waves_test": {
                    "date": "2018-03-06",
                    "status": "done"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "drop_test": {
                    "Properties": null
                  },
                  "waves_test": {
                    "date": "2018-03-06",
                    "status": "done"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "drop_test": {
                    "Properties": null
                  },
                  "waves_test": {
                    "date": "2018-03-06",
                    "status": ""
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "final_test": {
              "Properties": null
            }
          }
        }
      }';

$ar = json_decode($jsonString);

function recArr($array) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v) || is_object($v)) {
            recArr($v);
        } else {
            if ($k == 'status' && $v == '') {
                // some empty logic
                echo $k;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump(recArr($ar));
```

Comment: You guys are the best !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php), like so:

```
$array = json_decode($str, true); // Convert JSON string to array
$hasEmptyStatus = false;

try {
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($item, $key) {
        if ($key == "status" && $item == "") {
            throw new Exception;
        }
    });
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $hasEmptyStatus = true;
}

var_dump($hasEmptyStatus);
```

This code converts your JSON object into array, then runs recorsively on your array until it finds a key named "status" that it's value is empty, then it throws an exception in order to break the recorsive function since we found it, so no need to keep running on the array.

https://3v4l.org/LTa56

Comment: Thanks alot! Both solutions were great with a little tweaking!